# Redirect to error page from PHP code

Tags: php, http, redirect

In one moment I have to return http_response_code(503) from code. In ".htaccess"  file I have

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503.php
```

but everything what happens -

```
GET http://www.site.tk/ 503 (Service unavailable)
```

in Chrome console. How to automatically redirect to error page when php returns http error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ErrorDocument directive of htaccess is only used for errors thrown by the webserver. You'll have to handle the redirect from PHP.

Though I wouldn't use a redirect, I would keep the URL as is and simply show the contents of the error page (and do whatever it should do as well). That way the user may reload the site in case it was a temporary problem.